# XSLT - Catching parameters

Tags: asp.net, xslt

The situation is I have two xslt files: one is called from my ASP.NET code, and there, the second xslt file is imported.

What I'd like to accomplish is to pass a parameter to the first one so the second xslt(the one that is imported at the first xslt) can read it.

My c# code looks like this:

```
    var oArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
    oArgs.AddParam("fbLikeFeatureName", "", "Facebook_Like_Button");
    ltlContentBody.Text = xmlUtil.TransformXML(oXmlDoc, Server.MapPath(eSpaceId + "/styles/ExploringXSLT/ExploreContentObjects.xslt"), true);
```

And I'm catching the param at the first xslt this way:

```
<xsl:param name="fbLikeFeatureName" />
```

And then, passing it to the second xslt like this(previously, I import that file):

```
<xsl:call-template name="Articles">
    <xsl:with-param name="fbLikeFeatureName"></xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

Finally, I'm catching the param on the second xslt file as following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$fbLikeButtonName"/>
```

What Am I doing wrong? I'm kind of new at xslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "pass" the parameter from the first stylesheet to the imported stylesheet.  When you declare the param at the top level on the first stylesheet, it is automatically visible to all imported stylesheets.  Consider the following stylesheets:

template1.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="template2.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="input-param"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which imports template2.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:value-of select="$input-param"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I then transformed the following doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="template1.xsl"?>
<doc/>
```

with the input parameter "input-param" set to "This is a test".  I get the following output (Saxon-B 9.1.0.7):

```
This is a test
```

Comment: I don't know why I can't make it work...I'm doing everything you told me to.

Comment: Well, I'll admit I'm much more of a XSL expert than a C# expert, but where in your code sample are you attaching the parameter list to the transform?  I see where you create oArgs, and I see where you populate it, but it isn't mentioned on the line where you do the transform.

Comment: Poking around on the web, it looks like oArgs needs to be included as the third argument of xmlUtil.TransformXML().

Comment: Yes, you're both right. I included it before, but then I excluded it to test something and forgot to include it back. Thank you! It works great.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the value of the parameter when you pass it to the `Articles` template.  Try

```
<xsl:call-template name="Articles">
  <xsl:with-param name="fbLikeButtonName" select="$fbLikeFeatureName"/>
</xsl>
```

and ten

```
<xsl:template name="Articles">
  <xsl:param name="fbLikeButtonName"/>
   ...
  <xsl:value-of select="$fbLikeButtonName"/>
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

When using `with-param`, the name attribute is set to the name of the parameter as used by the called template (`Articles` in this case).  You then use `select` (or the body of `xsl:with-param`) to set the value.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't seem to be working though. At least no text is displaying on the browser(it's supposed to display the param's value).

Comment: Is the name attrobite of with-param precisely the same as the name attribute of param?  Does fbLikeFeatureName have a value outside of Articles?

Comment: Well, if you look at the ASP.NET code I wrote above you'll see its value is "Facebook_Like_Button".

Comment: @Brian I mean does it appear if you use it directly somewhere in the transform (including in Articles) rather than passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Also, I don't know ASP.NET, so I'm not certain where oargs is being used in the transform as it does not appear in the last line of code you gave